# Separate LEFT JOIN into some columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some tables that left join-ed. However, there is a table called Form the I am not sure how to combine the table with Table User.

Assume that there are three forms named form1, form2 and form3. I would like to get the latest status of each form for each email user.

p.s. Because of some reasons, the form record row is kept and insert a new row instead of just updating the form status after a cancel action.

Do I have to use union all ?

Table User

```
id    |  email
----------------------------
1     | testing1@testing.com
2     | testing2@testing.com
3     | testing3@testing.com
```

Table Form

```
email                    |  form  |  form_status | date
----------------------------------------------------------------------
testing1@testing.com     |  form1 |  completed   | 2018-08-01 12:00:00
testing1@testing.com     |  form2 |  cancelled   | 2018-08-02 12:00:00
testing1@testing.com     |  form2 |  completed   | 2018-08-03 12:00:00
testing1@testing.com     |  form3 |  cancelled   | 2018-08-04 12:00:00
testing2@testing.com     |  form1 |  cancelled   | 2018-08-05 12:00:00
testing2@testing.com     |  form2 |  completed   | 2018-08-06 12:00:00
```

My Goal to have the following result

```
id    |  email               | form1     | form2     | form3
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1     | testing1@testing.com | completed | completed | cancelled
2     | testing2@testing.com | cancelled | completed | null
3     | testing3@testing.com | null      | null      | null
```

I tried something like this but keep errors.

```
SELECT u.id, q.form_status as form1, u.email, 
u.last_successful_login as 'last login in', 
x.c1 as 'xc1', z.c2 as 'zc2' 
FROM user u 
left join yyyy x on u.email = x.email 
left join zzzz z on u.email = z.email 
UNION (
    SELECT
      form_status
    FROM Form f
    WHERE f.email = u.email and f.formtype = 'form1'
  ) q
ORDER BY u.id;
```

Comment: 1) Add a tag of your SQL language 2)you are looking for PIVOT. Search around for it...or wait 5 mins for an answer

Comment: How do you determine which status is the **latest** for a particular user and form? Do you have any timestamp column or perhaps an integer?

Comment: @KamilG. i have a date field, order by date desc

Comment: When you want to apply further logic you need a subquery, this can't be done with a simple join. Because you want to sort the data on the right.

Comment: @JimmyB I think it won't work because you want to MAX date for each form, not one MAX over all data. But let's try it I am not sure tho :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation with subquery :

```
select u.id, u.email, 
       max(case when f.form = 'form1' then f.form_status end) form1,
       max(case when f.form = 'form2' then f.form_status end) form2,
       max(case when f.form = 'form3' then f.form_status end) form3
from users u left join
     form f
     on f.email = u.email and 
        f.date = (select max(f1.date)
                  from form f1
                  where f1.email = f.email and f1.form = f.form
                 )
group by u.id, u.email;
```

Comment: some errors :( Error in query (1055): Expression #10 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'XXXXX.g.group_type' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by